# MacsiDigital/laravel-zoom Install failed in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, zooming

I tried to install https://github.com/MacsiDigital/laravel-zoom via composer. It gives me an error with guzzlehttp/guzzle version conflict.

```
Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.x-dev, 7.0.1]
```

How can I fix this?

This is my composer file.

- "php": "^7.2.5"
- "biscolab/laravel-recaptcha": "^4.1",
- "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
- "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
- "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
- "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
- "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
- "laravel/ui": "^2.1",
- "queueworker/sansdaemon": "^1.2",
- "softinklab/laravel-keyvalue-storage": "^1.3",
- "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.13",
- "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"

**Output (trimmed)**

$ composer require macsidigital/laravel-zoom

Using version ^4.0 for macsidigital/laravel-zoom

./composer.json has been updated

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: They updated the repo and fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a temporary fix. Downgrade your guzzle to 6.5.5 and install.

Issue raised in repo: https://github.com/MacsiDigital/laravel-api-client/issues/5